# Flux Query on Command Prompt

Tags: influxdb

I've been trying Flux query on command prompts few hours for simple query.
I'm using `InfluxDB 2.7` and `InfluxDB-Client 2.7.3`. Here is how my data look like in my bucket `first`

| _measurement | _field | _value | _time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| airSensors | co | 0.1 | 2023-07-14T00:36:52Z |
| airSensors | co | 0.2 | 2023-07-14T00:37:02Z |

This is my query
`from(bucket: "first") |> range(start: 2023-07-14T00:00:00Z, stop: now()) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "airSensors")`.
It runs success fully in `Data Explorer` but not `command prompt`. I got not idea why is this happening.
I've attached a image with my trials, where the query is runnable in `Data Explorer` but not `command promp`. Can someone help out?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself.

The query string should be enclosed with double quote `"`, value within the query should be escaped with backslash `\` only follow by double quote `"`.